# Need to get Opportunity ID

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem

I need to get Opportunity id to insert new OpportunityLineItem.. OrderProducts_*c object has master detail relationship to Order*_c which has lookup to Opportunity. I don't understand this code suppose to work.. If anybody can help me i will appreciate it

here is my error message:

> first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [Opportunity]: [Opportunity]:
>   Class.OrderLineItemProcess.onAfterInsert: line 41, column 1

```
    Map<Id, Order__c> ords = new Map<Id, Order__c>();

    set<Id> productIds=new set<Id>();
    Pricebook2 standartpb = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true and isActive= true limit 1];


    for(OrderProducts__c record: TriggerNew.values()) {
        productIds.add(record.products__c);
        ords.put(record.Id, null);
    }
    Map<Id, PricebookEntry> prices = new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>();

    for(PricebookEntry pricebook: [Select Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice,Pricebook2Id From PricebookEntry Where Product2Id IN :productIds and Pricebook2Id=:standartpb.Id])
    {
        prices.put(pricebook.Product2Id,pricebook);
    }


    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems=new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    for(OrderProducts__c record: TriggerNew.values()) 
    {
                OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem=new OpportunityLineItem(
                    PricebookEntryId=prices.get(record.Products__c).Id,
                    OpportunityId=record.order_mas__r.OpportunityLookup__c, **// required field is missing**
                    Quantity=record.Quantity__c,
                    Discount=record.Discount__c,
                    UnitPrice=record.Salesprice__c,
                    Description=record.LineDescription__c,
                    OrdLineItemExternalId__c=record.Id
                );
         lineItems.add(oppLineItem);

    }       
        FlaG.run=false;
        insert(lineItems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess :
If this error is happening during save of the OrderProducts record looks like

1) OrderProducts does not have order mas field( lookup) populated (or)

2) The opportunityLookup field related to the ordermas is not populated on the order mas record related to the orderproduct record you are trying to save.

If this error is happening when you are deploying/ running a test class

Your test class data is not populating the opportunity lookup data because of which the code might throw this error.

**Update:**

When you pointed out the trigger as below

```
trigger OLITrigger on OrderProducts__c (after insert) {

OrderLineItemProcess handler=new OrderLineItemProcess(); 

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert && FlaG.run) { 

handler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.newMap); 

} 

}
```

what happens here is that the trigger only passes field info related to orderProducts and none of the related list fields are pulled over when you use Trigger.new, Trigger.newmap

**if you need to associate the opptyId with order_mas_*r.OpportunityLookup*_c you need to query this data**

Change your

> > for(OrderProducts__c record: TriggerNew.values()) 
> >         { ..... ..... ....
>
> }

into

```
for(OrderProducts__c record: [selectProducts__c,order_mas__r.OpportunityLookup__c,Quantity__c,Discount__c,Salesprice__, LineDescription__c,OrdLineItemExternalId__c from OrderProducts__c where Id IN: TriggerNew.values()) 
        {
          ......
          .....
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but orderProducts have order mas field i checked and also the opportunityLookup field is populated i have no idea why this is happening :/

Comment: @user7361 are u getting this error when saving a record/ running a test class?

Comment: Also can u paste the query/ method you are using to populate TriggerNew, could be possible that you forgot to add the field in the query

Comment: i get that error when i try to save a record. i dont have a test class yet actually i am working on it right now. that code block is a part of my handler class btw

Comment: @user7361 please post the method where you are populating the TriggerNew map

Comment: public void onAfterInsert(Map<Id,OrderProducts__c> TriggerNew) this is my only defination of TriggerNew i didnt populate it

Comment: can you go to setup--> objects --> create --> orderProducts__c and under triggers see if there is a trigger that calls the class on which this onAfterInsert method lives and paste the place where the trigger calls this class.methodname?

Comment: trigger OLITrigger on OrderProducts__c (after insert) {
OrderLineItemProcess handler=new OrderLineItemProcess();
   if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert && FlaG.run)
    {
        handler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.newMap);
    }
}  this is my trigger

Comment: So this clarifies why the error comes up, ill update my answer